# Nodejs Pkg - how to use an external Config file?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am having issues attempting to properly use pkg (nodejs module) properly.

I am doing a stand alone file manager (well,   it would swap video/audio files to & from preselected directories, intended to allow it without any internet connection it self to remove & add files to a syncing folder like onedrive/dropbox/googledrive/etc.  using a text file.)

The issue I am having, is I am at a loss of after I package it into a binary.. I do not understand how to allow/force it to create/read the text file outside compiled binary.
-- I would love for it to be within the same folder as the executable.

I am attempting to find a way to store data without having to share the sourcecode, or require node be installed on other machines.
-- I intend to have a minimal permissions as possible, and outside reading/writing the config & 'database' [which is simply a text file with what files are in the local storage, and what files are & are not in the remote storage]

What am I missing about pkg, & if it can store data internally some how... how do I get it to read an external file?
-- Though I would greatly prefer to have the txt files outside the binary & in plain text easy to read.

---

As a side question, I am not understanding how to pass an argument through & use it inside the program after it's compiled.  [Hell, I'm having a heck of a time, properly understanding the readme for the pkg module]

Answer (score 4):

Use fs features to load config object as in this three-lines of code

```
filename="./config.json";
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(filename);
let config = JSON.parse(rawdata);
```

config.json must be in same direcory of pkg executable

If you need to change path of config.json, you will able to specify full-path of this file using command line arguments.
These can be read at runtime using process.argv variable as explained [here](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `process.cwd()` to get the current working directory of your express app or pkg .exe and then you can load a config file during runtime from your file system.

```
const configPath = process.cwd() + '/config.json';  // loads config.json from the same directory as your .exe
const configData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(configPath, 'utf8'));
```